# Complex parallelogram button shapes

Tags: css, svg, css-shapes

I was wondering if it was possible to do complex buttons like this in CSS3? I'm not sure where to start. I can do the trapezoidal like shape easily, but adding a border to that seems to be impossible. Am I missing something?

(PS: picture is form Deus Ex Human Revolution)

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you have yourself pointed out, generating the shape given in question is pretty easy and the below is a sample snippet on how to achieve it. The basic idea is to use a pseudo-element, add `background` to it and then skew it. The `overflow: hidden` on the parent would cut out the part of the shape that is not required and thus end up producing the shape.

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-position: inside;
}
li {
  position: relative;
  height: 40px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: right;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-radius: 8px;
  color: crimson;
  overflow: hidden;
}
li:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  transform: skew(45deg);
  z-index: -1;
}

/* just for demo */

body {
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/800/500/abstract/2);
}
*, *:after, *:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Menu Text 1</li>
  <li>Menu Text 2</li>
  <li>Menu Text 3</li>
</ul>
```

However, adding borders to the shape that is created using this method is very tough and the fact that there needs to be a transparent area between the shape and its border makes it almost impossible.

---

We can use `clip-path` like in the below snippet and it would have made it possible for a border to be added using a pseudo-element but this approach has the following drawbacks:

- Pure CSS version of `clip-path` is not supported by Firefox and IE (all versions).
- Even the inline SVG based `clip-path` would be supported only in Chrome and Firefox.
- While the `clip-path` can be modified to produce that transparent area between the background and the border, it would make it ultra-complex and almost impossible to maintain.
- Assigning a transparent or semi-transparent background color would cause problems because there is another element behind and so the colors would blend like in the below snippet.

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-position: inside;
}
li {
  position: relative;
  height: 40px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: right;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background: crimson;
  color: crimson;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 0% 50%, 10% 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 50%, 90% 0%);
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 0% 50%, 10% 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 50%, 90% 0%);
}
li:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: calc(100% - 4px);
  width: calc(100% - 4px);
  left: 2px;
  top: 2px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 0% calc(50% - 1px), 10% 100%, 100% 100%, 100% calc(50% + 1px), 90% 0%);
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 0% calc(50% - 1px), 10% 100%, 100% 100%, 100% calc(50% + 1px), 90% 0%);
  z-index: -1;
}

/* just for demo */

body {
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/800/500/abstract/2);
}
*, *:after, *:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>Menu Text 1</li>
  <li>Menu Text 2</li>
  <li>Menu Text 3</li>
</ul>
```

---

Given all the above, I would suggest you to **use SVG** for producing such complex shapes. With SVG, we can use the `path` elements to create both the border and the fill for the shape.

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-position: inside;
}
li {
  position: relative;
  height: 40px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: right;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-radius: 8px;
  color: crimson;
}
li.active {
  width: 350px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
}
svg #fill {
  fill: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
svg #border {
  stroke: crimson;
  stroke-width: 2;
  fill: transparent;
}
li svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}

/* just for demo */

body {
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/800/500/abstract/2);
}
*, *:after, *:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<svg viewBox='0 0 300 40' height='0' width='0'>
  <defs>
    <g id='shape'>
      <path d='M8,0 A8,8 0 0,0 0,8 L0,20 30,40 292,40 A8,8 0 0,0 300,32 L300,20 270,0z' id='fill' />
    </g>
    <g id='shape-bordered'>
      <path d='M9,1 A8,8 0 0,0 1,9 L1,20 30,39 292,39 A8,8 0 0,0 299,32 L299,20 270,1z' id='border' />
      <path d='M10,4 A7,7 0 0,0 4,6 L4,19 31,36 290,36 A5,5 0 0,0 296,34 L296,21 269,4z' id='fill' />
    </g>
  </defs>
</svg>
<ul>
  <li class='active'>
    <svg viewBox='0 0 300 40' preserveAspectRatio='none'>
      <use xlink:href='#shape-bordered' />
    </svg>Menu Text 1</li>
  <li>
    <svg viewBox='0 0 300 40' preserveAspectRatio='none' vector-effect='non-scaling-stroke'>
      <use xlink:href='#shape' />
    </svg>Menu Text 2</li>
  <li>
    <svg viewBox='0 0 300 40' preserveAspectRatio='none'>
      <use xlink:href='#shape' />
    </svg>Menu Text 3</li>
</ul>
```

<sup>*(The SVG could probably be tuned further. The above snippet is only a sample to illustrate what can be achieved.)*</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! I am going to play around with your code sample.